# How to remove the similar text from one column by comparing with other column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following example

```
addressid  23915031 
customerid 13154569
address1   FLAT NO 23 3Road Floor KRISH  BUILDING ANUSHKTI  
address2   GAR BARC COLONY Near SECTOR MARKET
address3   MANKHURoad MUMBAI
landmark   ANUOHAKTING  
zipcode    400094   
addresstype RESIDENCE ADDRESS
cityname   MUMBAI   
statedesc  MAHARASHTRA
```

In the above example I want to remove Mumbai from address3 field by comapring with cityname field. How to perform this in SQL server.
Please help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this to address all the things:

```
UPDATE yourtable 
SET address3 = REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(address3))),LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(cityname))),'')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below script.

```
SELECT REPLACE (address3,cityname,'')
FROM Yourtable
```

If you wanted to update 'address3' column  use the below script.

```
UPDATE Yourtable
SET address3   =REPLACE (address3,cityname,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Replace** and **LTRIM**, **RTRIM**:

**Replace:** it will replace your occurrence word to new word

**LTRIM :** remove left side blank space

**RTRIM :** remove rightside blank space

```
DECLARE @Address VARCHAR(100)='MANKHURoad MUMBAI',@City VARCHAR(50)='MUMBAI'
SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@Address)),LTRIM(RTRIM(@City)),'')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Replace Function](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/replace.php). But please also look for any extra space or upper or lower case scenarios.